# css clear floats with multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to clear the floats after the left and the right div..ie; left div should match the whole size of right div..but unfortunately I dont see it working.

css

```
#left{
    float:left;
    background-color:gray
}

#right{
    float:left;
    background-color:gray
}
```

html

```
<div>

    <div id="left">
       <ul id="ul1" style="list-style-type:none">
          <li><a style="color:orange" href="/">About Us</a></li>
                        <br>
          <li><a style="color:orange" href="/players">Players</a></li>
                        <br>
         <li><a style="color:orange" href="/contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

    <div id="right">
        THis is some content.
        <br>
        THis is some content.
            <br>
        THis is some content.
                <br>
        THis is some content.
                    <br>
        THis is some content.
                        <br>
        THis is some content.

                            <br>
        THis is some content.
                                <br>
        THis is some content.
                                    <br>
        THis is some content.<br>
        THis is some content.
    </div>
     <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
                                     <div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/verja6oh/

Comment: Why would you expect setting the floats to have any effect on an item's size?

Comment: How do I match the size of the left div to the right div?..The contents on the right div are dynamically generated using Javascript

Answer (score 0):

There's a very cool trick on how to do this.

First, you apply `padding-bottom:100%;` to each div.

Next, you apply `margin-bottom:-100%;` to each div.

Finally, you add `overflow:hidden;` to the div they are inside.

Presto! True happiness is yours.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/verja6oh/1/)

**css:**

```
#top{background:yellow;overflow:hidden;}
#left{float:left;background-color:gray;padding-bottom:100%;margin-bottom:-100%;}
#right{float:left;background-color:gray;padding-bottom:100%;margin-bottom:-100%;}
```

**Note that I added an ID to the container div so that it could be styled.**

References:

http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61

Comment: I tried to make the content a bit longer (longer than the screen) and the left div only grew to the screen height, leaving a gap if you scroll down

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you could try

```
<div id="Column">
<p> Content </P
</div>

<div id="Column1">
<p> Content </P
</div>
```

Use CSS to float column to the left. And column1 to the right.
Set width attribute on both to 50%.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the display property to table-cell (you will implicitly get a table row and a table around those)

```css
#left{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:gray
}

#right{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:gray
}
```